# jqGrid: formatter: "actions" doesn't work for remote json url

Tags: json, jqgrid, action, formatter, free-jqgrid

I tried to use jqGrid formatter: "actions" for remote json url but it shifts rows because number of column names and actual returned data doesn't match (act column is extra one in column names). I did search online and it looks like all examples are for local data (on page) where json is used as key/value, while url:somepage.php returns a csv kind-of-format of columns(no keys, just values). Also I use id as hidden field, while all examples show id. I use one more hidden column as well.
here is my colmodel:

```
url: "manager_json",
                editurl: "manager_edit",
                datatype: "json",
                //data: mydata,
                width:1000,
                //jsonReader: {
                //                repeatitems : false,
                //           },
                colNames: ["","Id","Uid","Custom Id","Image Name","Coord. X","Coord. Y","Gender","Progress","Status","Created","Updated"], 
                colModel: [{"name":"act","template":"actions","formatoptions":{"editformbutton":true}},{"name":"id","align":"center","width":33,"editable":false,"hidden":true},{"name":"uid","align":"center","width":33,"editable":true,"hidden":true,"editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false}},{"name":"ta_id","align":"center","width":100,"editrules":{"required":true}},{"name":"image","width":150,"template":"text","editrules":{"required":true}},{"name":"x","width":100,"align":"center","template":"integer","editrules":{"required":true}},{"name":"y","width":100,"align":"center","template":"integer","editrules":{"required":true}},{"name":"gender","width":100,"align":"center","formatter":"select","stype":"select","editrules":{"required":true},"edittype":"select","editoptions":{"value":"f:Female;m:Male","defaultValue":"m"},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne"],"value":":Any;f:Female;m:Male"}},{"name":"progress","width":120,"align":"center","formatter":"select","stype":"select","editrules":{"required":true},"editable":false,"edittype":"select","editoptions":{"value":"-:New;pf:Process Failed;ps:Process Scheduled;pss:Process Success;p:Processing...;s:Staging;tf:Test Failed;ts:Test Scheduled;tss:Test Success;t:Testing...","defaultValue":"m"},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne"],"value":":Any;-:New;pf:Process Failed;ps:Process Scheduled;pss:Process Success;p:Processing...;s:Staging;tf:Test Failed;ts:Test Scheduled;tss:Test Success;t:Testing..."}},{"name":"status","width":100,"align":"center","formatter":"select","stype":"select","edittype":"select","editoptions":{"value":"a:Active;n:New","defaultValue":"m"},"searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne"],"value":":Any;a:Active;n:New"}},{"name":"date_created","width":150,"template":"text","editable":false},{"name":"last_updated","width":150,"template":"text","editable":false}]
```

And here is my actual data from my server (db) as per jqgrid specification:

```
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":7,"rows":[{"id":32,"cell":[32,"889daf31ff3e49544f52850258439600","2uu","2ok",2,2,"m","-","a","2017-02-10 18:57:05","2017-02-10 23:37:12"]},{"id":30,"cell":[30,"","11","11",1,1,"m","-","a","2017-02-10 18:01:52","2017-02-10 18:01:52"]},{"id":29,"cell":[29,"aaa","ww222111uu","11",1,1,"m","-","a","2017-02-10 18:00:36","2017-02-10 23:37:08"]},{"id":27,"cell":[27,"","11","1",1,1,"m","-","a","2017-02-10 17:57:41","2017-02-10 17:57:41"]},{"id":25,"cell":[25,"","4tt","4img",4,4,"f","-","n","2017-02-10 17:50:21","2017-02-11 00:26:03"]},{"id":24,"cell":[24,"","1","1",1,1,"m","-","a","2017-02-10 17:49:38","2017-02-10 17:49:38"]},{"id":22,"cell":[22,"","bbb","imam 222",2,22,"f","p","n","2017-02-08 20:14:55","2017-02-10 13:27:57"]}]}
```

As you can see cell row has less columns than `colNames` and `colModel`. Also id and `uid` columns are hidden. I added on extra fake column from db, but it did not help

i am using jqGrid 4.13.7-pre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to return objects like

```json
{
    "id": 32,
    "uid": "889daf31ff3e49544f52850258439600",
    "ta_id": "2uu",
    "image": "2ok",
    "x": 2,
    "y": 2,
    "gender": "m",
    "progress": "-",
    "status": "a",
    "date_created": "2017-02-10 18:57:05",
    "last_updated": "2017-02-10 23:37:12"
}
```

instead of

```json
{
    "id": 32,
    "cell": [
        32, "889daf31ff3e49544f52850258439600", "2uu", "2ok", 2, 2, "m", "-", "a",
        "2017-02-10 18:57:05", "2017-02-10 23:37:12"
    ]
}
```

as the server response. It will simplify your code.

If you do need to process the current format of the data, then you will have to force `repeatitems: false` mode by usage the option

```js
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false
}
```

and to use `jsonmap` property of `colModel` to inform jqGrid from which element of the item one should read the column data. The `jsonmap` could be either in the string form like

```js
jsonmap: "cell.1"
```

or in the function form:

```js
jsonmap: function (item) {
    return item.cell[1];
}
```

To make the code better maintainable you can define an object like

```js
var columnOrder = {
        id: 0,
        uid: 1,
        ta_id: 2,
        image: 3,
        x: 4,
        y: 5,
        gender: 6,
        progress: 7,
        status: 8,
        date_created: 9,
        last_updated: 10
    };
```

which provides the index in `cell` array by the column name and to use `jsonmap` like

```js
jsonmap: function (item) {
    return item.cell[columnOrder.uid];
}
```

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ozzgnaeh/2/ demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Reason I was going to use array format (not a dictionary format) because I expected to have about 5000 rows per page and therefore to minimize load time and size. The suggested data format helped. Works now. Thank you Oleg.

Comment: I dont see any button which says "accept this answer" ... where is it?

Comment: @LSP: The word "accept" (see my previous comment) is the link, which you can click to see how you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you Oleg (I hate those gray invisible colors) .. done now :)